# Add Satellite View to MKMapKit IOS 6 with 3D Capability

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, mkmapview

Does anyone know how to grant an application's mapView access to the Satellite View (like in the Apple Maps application)? I currently have a working MKMapView for ios6 and would like to allow the user to switch between the satellite and normal maps. Any help would be awesome thanks!

EDIT:

Sorry I forgot to specify the Satellite view with 3D capability like in Apple Maps. What would this require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`mapType`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MKMapView/mapType) property of your map view to [`MKMapTypeSatellite`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/MKMapTypeSatellite)

Comment: Hey thanks man!! Do you also know how to add the 3d capability to the satellite view?

Comment: @ttarules That is not possible I'm afraid. You should file a [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com) and request the API for this to be exposed.

Comment: Thats a good call, I'll do that! Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: @tdevoy : did you find anything for support 3d in mkmapview in iOS 6?